# Formula field not evaluated in trigger.new in test class only

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing a test class for a trigger (after update in this case), and while the code works on my person account record page *when I inline edit*, it does not work in my test class when I *manually change the field* that would re-evaluate the formula to true/false. The problem it seems is that the formula field does not get evaulated in Trigger.New while I'm executing the test class. here's where the code breaks:

Trigger code - this is where I get different results in inline vs. test class change. Enrolled_Within_Past_Year__pc is the formula field:

```
if(triggerNew.get(i).Enrolled_Within_Past_Year__pc != triggerOld.get(i).Enrolled_Within_Past_Year__pc){
 ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if a formula has changed its value within `Apex Trigger`, `Workflow Rule`, or `Process Builder`. The value is calculated at retrieval time, so you can only ever get one value. What you are attempting is impossible.

See, for example, [An Introduction to Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas)
 (emphasis mine):

> Objects persisted in the database tend to have field types that store data, for example numbers or text. They can also have a formula field type, which is **calculated at run-time** much like formulas in a spreadsheet. Besides their use as a field type, formulas are used to determine when certain actions should occur on the platform, for example when a workflow rule should fire, and in validation rules that determine when data is bona fide.

Comment: Do you have a link supporting this behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adrian. That is great information to learn from. I just want to know, why is it the case that when I do inline edit, the formula field value has been re-calculated and *triggerNew.get(i).Enrolled_Within_Past_Year__pc != triggerOld.get(i).Enrolled_Within_Past_Year__pc* equates to true?

Comment: adrian - please note: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/45346/2602